# Why this PHP command work on XAMPP web server but not on IIS?

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, xampp

I am working on a web application. I want to know who took a survey. I can get the computer name, but that doesnt help me since multiple users can log into a computer. So to know who is logged in I was using this in my PHP file:

```
exec("wmic /node:$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR] COMPUTERSYSTEM Get UserName", $user); echo $user[1];
```

This was working great, as it would tell me the username and i was using a XAMPP server(testing phase). Now i published it on IIS7 and it is not working? Can anyone help me understand why?

I am trying to find the who is taking the survey, by finding out who is logged in on the machine? This will be over intranet.

Comment: Does any PHP code work on your IIS7 setup?

Comment: I inserted a info.php on the project folder(survey) which just had phpinfo(); on it. I ran http://localhost/survey/info.php and it showed that php information. So i am assuming your answer to your question is yes?

Comment: Is the default path consistent between the two servers? If not, then one server won't execute wmic. Also, are all the components wmic requires still installed and functioning correctly?

Comment: How can i check that? I am not entirely sure? For xampp, i did not configure anything, just installed it, typed that command and it worked. Sorry for being ignorant about this?

Comment: in PHP, use `echo getcwd();` to display the working folder on the screen. Then to test to see if wmic executes, open a command prompt, type `cd folder` where `folder` is what was displayed on the screen then press enter then type `wmic`.  If you get an error like `bad command or file name` or similar then you know you have the wrong folder.

Comment: @Mike I just did what your asked. When i type wmic and press enter, there is a line below and it has: `wmic:root\cli>`. So i am assuming it is one the right working folder?

Comment: yes. I haven't used wmic but from the message, it looks like you're in a special command prompt run by wmic